# Speeding up Selenium Webdriver

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver (2.0) under the Perl language bindings, with Firefox 20. It is incredibly slow. For example, one common operation is to fill in a couple of `<input type="text">` fields with an ID and password. I could type it in 2 to 3 times faster than Selenium does a 'send_keys' method. Locating elements, such as a table cell with specific text in a large table, is like watching paint dry.

I thought that maybe there is some sort of default speed setting that wasn't at its highest value, but the get_speed and set_speed methods have been removed. So, is Selenium already running flat out, or is there some setting I can tweak? I've seen many questions about how to *slow down* Selenium, but at this time I'm looking for how to *speed it up*. I'll worry about slowing it down later, if necessary.

- Perl: Strawberry Perl 5.16.3 (driver for test program)
- Java: 1.7.0_21-b11 (for the Selenium Server .jar file)  (32 bit)
- Selenium::Remote::Driver:  0.16 via CPAN (Perl language bindings)
- Selenium-Server-Standalone: 2.32.0
- OS:  Windows 7 Professional, SP 1  (64 bit)
- hardware: Dell Precision T1650 (Xeon 3.5GHz 16GB RAM)
- browser:  Firefox 20.0.1 with Selenium IDE 1.10.0 (production users will have Chrome, IE9, Opera)

Since even an "atomic" operation such as entering text into an input field is so slow, I don't think it's an issue with using XPath locators rather than CSS, or Perl instead of some other language. It's been suggested that I try Chrome instead of FF -- can it help *that* much? I do a lot of locating text within table cells, so CSS locators are unfortunately of limited value.

Thanks much for any help on this! I'm going to look real bad if this test automation isn't faster than manually running the tests!

Comment: I moved away from Selenium to using the Mozilla platform APIs to directly drive Firefox (e.g: writing "privileged" JavaScript code). Its only performance bottleneck is waiting for HTTP responses. These APIs will, however, require that you learn a *lot* more about the internals of Mozilla applications.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if downgrading Firefox a few versions has any bearing. Not saying that's a solution if it works, but it would be interesting to know if the version of Firefox has any bearing on the problem.

Comment: If there was a way to speed up browsers driven by Selenium, then you'd think that the Selenium dev team would have come up with something for us, but they didn't.

Comment: I'm still in the midst of rewriting a lot of test code, especially to use exact text = rather than contains(). Since I upgraded to FF 21, it seems to go a LOT faster, even the text entry operations. When I'm done with this, I'll try to remember to report back here.

Comment: Still not as fast as I'd like, but FF 22 and exact text tests seem to be fast enough for now. Not done yet, but enough of it is that I think it will be usable.

Comment: Are these all Ajax pages you're interacting with? If not, HtmlUnit would be a much faster driver.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but there is the phantom driver http://phantomjs.org/ which doesn't use a screen driver and can be hooked into selenium.

```
  ./phantomjs --webdriver=5556 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://localhost:4444
```

Or link it to a remote hub

Answer (score 0):

This may not be directly applicable,  but you can follow a few simple tips to first investigate where most of the time is spent. Look at the article below:

https://blog.mavenhive.in/7-tips-to-speed-up-your-webdriver-tests-4f4d043ad581

I guess most of these are generic steps which would apply irrespective of the tool used for testing too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question:

Selenium tests have evolved in a lot of ways and they are running at faster speeds than before.

But in order to make your tests run much faster, use the `headless` mode, which does not open any windows for testing. It is available, both in `chromedriver` and `geckodriver`.