# Speed up selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, performance, selenium

I'm using selenium webdriver to automate web page usage.  Headless browser not allowed.

Selenium seems rather slow at finding multiple elements on a single page that is fully loaded.

Does anyone have any tips for how to speed things up?  I am generally searching for objects via xpath.

I have searched google and read [similar SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863992/speeding-up-selenium-webdriver).  I am looking for new ideas

Comment: Search elements by ID or by cssSelector. Xpath is usually the slowest. Use ExpectedConditions, avoid using thread.sleeps. Use caching with pagefactories. Buy a faster CPU, more RAM, faster internet connection. Also, the question seems to be pretty broad.

Comment: cool, that's helpful, thank you

Comment: @skandigraun "Xpath is usually the slowest" has not been true for a few years now! The answer to the CSS versus XPath debate is now: "depends"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case i like to create a org.​w3c.​dom Document using the page source and then parse it using the javax.xml libary:

```
public static Document getWebpageDocument_fromSource(String source) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    try {
        HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
        CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
        props.setAllowHtmlInsideAttributes(true);
        props.setAllowMultiWordAttributes(true);
        props.setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true);
        props.setOmitComments(true);

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(source);

        Document doc = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);

        return doc;
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then accessing elements via xpath like this:

```
String myXpathStr = "//*[@id='news-main']/div";
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList articleBlocks = (NodeList)xPath.compile(myXpathStr).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

hope that helps.  i also agree with the other answers that id and css are faster.  i've found xpath to be more powerful but I don't have a lot of experience with css paths

Answer (score 0):

I search by `id`, `class name` and other easily identifiable elements. But speed is going to be based on things like network connection and hardware. You can alway use the `HTMLDriver`, as this will be the quickest version of the driver.